# How can I substitute "focus"?

Tags: html, css

I'm programming a responsive menu, however I used "focus" - so when I click it doesn't go to where I sent the link, only if I tab to it. How can I solve it?

```
button:focus ~ .nav-item{
    height: 330px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1117px) {
.nav-item{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        align-items: flex-end;
        height: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on what a click on the button _already_ does ... I would add a class to the button when clicked so you could use a selector like `button:focus ~ .nav-item, button.chosen ~ .nav-item` — but you're not showing any of your html structure or what you might be doing with javascript so I can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of all events here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event

Pick the one (or multiple) that fits your use case. Especially if you're developing for desktop and mobile, you might need mouse and touch events.